# R extract() doesn´t accept my coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, raster

First of all, I´m new to programing so this might be a simple question but i cant find the solution anywhere.

I´ve been using this code to extract values from a set of stacked rasters:

```
raster.files <- list.files() 
raster.list <- list()
raster.files <-list.files(".",pattern ="asc")

for(i in 1: length(raster.files)){
raster.list[i] <- raster(raster.files[i])}

stacking <- stack(raster.list)
coord <- read.csv2("...")
extract.data <- extract(stacking,coord,method="simple")
```

I already used this code several times without any problem, until now. Every time I run the extract line I get this error:

```
Error in .doCellFromXY(object@ncols, object@nrows, object@extent@xmin,  : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

The coord file consists in a data.frame with 2 columns(X and Y respectively).

Answer (score 0):

I´ve managed to found a way to bypass this error, its not technically a solution because I can´t understand why R was treating my data as text instead in first place.

Basically I separated the X and Y columns and treated them individually and then binded them again in a new data.frame:

```
coord_matrix_x<-as.numeric(as.matrix(coord[1]))
coord_matrix_y<-as.numeric(as.matrix(coord[2]))
coord2 <- cbind(coord_matrix_x, coord_matrix_y)
coord2<-as.data.frame(coord2)
coordinates(coord2)<-c("coord_matrix_x","coord_matrix_y")
```

It´s far form the most elegant way to do it, but it just works.